# Regex for letters plus space

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regex for testing for only letters and spaces allowed in an input field. I tried using `/^[a-zA-Z]*$/` but this doesn't allow spaces.

Updated this question. I'm looking to only have one space between words.
So for example I have a city name like New Orleans so only letters and one space between words should be allowed.

Comment: Why do you need to restrict the valid input with respect to the number of spaces? If you're asking the user to enter a city name, then allow them to type as many spaces as they want and then remove multiple spaces. So somebody could then type "New<space><space>Orleans" and your code would understand that as "New<space>Orleans".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[a-aA-Z]` character class, and `\s` character classes have the following caveats.

`a-zA-Z` may be too restrictive if you wish to accept Unicode, in which case, \p{Alpha} would be a better character class.

`\s` may be either too permissive or too restrictive depending on the Unicode or ASCII semantics under which your regex is operating.  You may only want to just put a single space in the character class.

If we knew what language and whether or not you intend for Unicode semantics, that might help.  Things aren't as simple as they were back in the ASCII-only days.

**Update:**

Here's a more robust solution that still has the original Unicode caveats, but allows for a single space character between words, and nowhere else.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @cities = (
  'New Orleans',
  'New Jersey',
  'Salt Lake City',
  'Sacramento',
  ' Leading space',
  'Trailing space ',
  'Two  consecutive spaces',
  '  Two leading spaces',
  'Two trailing spaces  ',
);

foreach my $city ( @cities ) {
  print "<<$city>>: ";
  if( $city =~ m/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$/ ) {
    print "match\n";
  }
  else {
    print "reject\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great but I only want to allow single spaces. Right now it allows multiple spaces.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question and define exactly what it is you want.  It sounds like you want "I want to allow any letters, plus possibly one space, but only one space", but maybe not, because I can't tell what you mean.

Comment: Do this?  `/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/ && !/\s{2,}/` (for example), but then the next question will probably be how to prevent space at start and end of the string, and we begin getting into an ever-growing spec that starts to move beyond language-agnostic solutions.

Comment: @ericb Updated my post with another regex example.

Answer (score 0):

Matches multiple groups of letters separated by single spaces.

```
(\w+ )+\w
```

Comment: Of course \w matches digits and underscore, and under Unicode, about 100,000+ other things.  And this requires a minimum of 2 characters, separated by space, to match.